# Applying SuiteScript on a NetSuite page got error "MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST"

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0, netsuite-rest-api

After applying Suitescript
I am trying to deploy my user event script on vendor form but I always got "MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST" error.

ERROR STATEMENT: `{"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Module does not exist: /SuiteScripts/AddFilterButton.js","stack":[]}`

[image]

Here is SuiteScript:

```
/**
@NApiVersion 2.0
@NScriptType UserEventScript
@NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(['N/ui/serverWidget','N/log'], function (serverWidget,log) {

    function beforeLoad(context) {
        try{
            if (context.type === context.UserEventType.VIEW) {
                var form = context.form;
                
                var customButton = form.addButton({
                  id: 'custpage_filter_button',
                  label: 'Filter Button',
                });
                
                customButton.isDisabled = false;
                
            }
        }catch(ex){
            log.error({
                title: "Error",
                details: ex.message
            })
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    };
});
```

Comment: as I understood, you are having this when you try to deploy. So probably there is no file /SuiteScripts/AddFilterButton.js. At least I'd look into that direction

Comment: You said you have deployed the script on the vendor form. Have you tried deploying the script at a global level? I.e. Via SETUP > CUSTOMISATION > SCRIPTING?

Comment: Also - I see a difference between the error message in your screenshot and what you have shared. "Module does not exist: /SuiteScripts/AddFilterButton.js" .... on the screenshot, the file points to "/SuiteScripts/Filter_Button.js". Little confusing. Which one is it? AddFilterButton.js OR Filter_Button.js?

Comment: Thank you so much @Dmity for pointing out that I missed the AddFilterButton.js file when reviewing my SuiteScript directory. After investigating the SuiteScript directory, I realized that I did miss the AddFilterButton.js file in my directory.